# Шаблон файла robots.txt

Tags: html

Мне нужно сделать файл robots.txt для сайта компании. Есть ли robots.txt вместе с подсказками по оформлению или всё придётся по отдельности искать?

Comment: Гуглится просто: https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt?hl=ru + https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html + https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл robots.txt это текстовый файл, который содержит параметры индексирования сайта для роботов поисковых систем, и выглядит он так:

```
User-agent: * #указываем, для каких роботов установлены директивы
Disallow: /bin/ # запрещает ссылки из "Корзины с товарами".
Disallow: /search/ # запрещает ссылки страниц встроенного на сайте поиска
Disallow: /admin/ # запрещает ссылки из панели администратора
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap # указываем роботу на файл sitemap для сайта
Clean-param: ref /some_dir/get_book.pl
```

Для успешного индексирования сайта необходимо задать нужные параметры директивам из таблицы выше!)